# Emacs org-mode capture -> file+datetree+prompt template help

Tags: emacs, capture, org-mode

Hey org-mode fanatics. I'm wanting to set up my org-capture journal template to use `file+datetree+prompt` to dynamically set up date on creation (instead of using `file+datetree` which automatically sets date to today).

When I replace file+datetree with `file+datetree+prompt` in my template,

```
("j" "Journal" entry (file+datetree+prompt "~/Dropbox/doc/journal.org")
     "* %?\n----Entered on %U\n  %i\n  %a")))
```

I receive error: "Invalid capture target specification.

I've tried messing with this template quite a bit and haven't had success yet. I'd appreciate any help on how to properly set up my journal template. Thanks!

Here's a link to the info page on file+datetree+prompt: [Template Elements](http://orgmode.org/manual/Template-elements.html#Template-elements)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The manual page you mentioned is the *development version* of the manual. The template target element *file+datetree+prompt* was introduced in commit [341e9ce1d7085316c78d92f19790ad828c15731e](http://orgmode.org/w/?p=org-mode.git;a=commitdiff;h=341e9ce1d7085316c78d92f19790ad828c15731e) which was part of release 7.4:

```
$ git name-rev --name-only 341e9ce1d7085316c78d92f19790ad828c15731e
tags/release_7.4~44
```

(means: commit 341…e was introduced 44 commits before tag release_7.4)

So you just have to update to the latest release or you can also [use the development version](http://orgmode.org/worg/org-faq.html#Keeping-current) of Org-Mode.

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is there is no documentation for file+datetree+prompt.
Try file+datetree instead. I had good results from that.

```
("j" "Journal" entry (file+datetree "~/Dropbox/doc/journal.org")
     "* %?\n----Entered on %U\n  %i\n  %a")))
```

Resulted in this entry on the file journal.org: 
(using the word 'Test' when prompted)

```
* 2010
** 2010-12 December
*** 2010-12-20 Monday
**** Test
----Entered on [2010-12-20 Mon 12:12]
```

Looking at the source code for org v7.3, there is no reference to file-datetree-prompt, although I did see it mentioned in an online manual. It would be a nice feature, but I'm just manually changing the date in the entry window itself if that's necessary.

Comment: For now, I've found a work-around. On your agenda view, you can press k -> c to capture for that day. This will add to the datetree according to your selected day. So if you want to journal for yesterday, navigate to yesterday in agenda, then kc.